# Where can I find proper field?

Tags: c#, types, field, instance, primitive

I have two lines of simple code.

```
int x = 12 * 30;
MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
```

First line : I understand that `x` is an `instance` of type int.

Second line : So, I used the `ToString` method of type int.

Question :

How can I put the value `12*30` into the instance `x` without using the "field" of int type?

How can I get the value `12*30` from the instance `x` without using the "field" of  int type?

Am I missing something now?

Regards

EDIT 1)

Maybe,, I did not make myself clear enough.

I'd like to shed a light to my question with different direction.

For the first line) I heard that the "x" is an instance of type int. (C# 5.0 in a Nutshell pg.15 "Predefined Type Example"). And I thought, an instance can not have any kind of value (int/string whatever kind) directly. So, I thought it needs a field to put a value. That is my first question.

EDIT 2)

The 2nd question is basically identical to the 1st question. The instance "x" has value now (somewhere inside of it, I do not know where it is, the value is 360). As you can see it, it make a good result with "instance.method" style. I thought its style should be "field.method". That is my second question(I have some kind of cofusion with 2nd question though).

EDIT 3)

I just made my questions with wondering feelings. I do not want to make any kind of bizarre route to accomplish something. I just wondering how it works nicely even without any "FIELD". It is so inconsistent with other type's ways of (normal) working. It is so confusing.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking.  Do you just want to store "12*30" as a string?  Do you want to use type inference, eg, `var` instead of `int`.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: What do you mean by "field"? Every object should have its type.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you mean or what you're trying to achieve, I'm afraid. (Note that local variables aren't fields, by the way.) The value of `x` is 360. If you wanted to represent the operation "multiplying 12 by 30" you can't do it that way... by the time the expression has been evaluated, there's *no* difference between that and `int x = 359 + 1;`

Comment: _A field is a variable of any type that is declared directly in a class or struct. Fields are members of their containing type._  Skip forward to Page 67 C# in a Nutshell.

Comment: @DarrenYoung Thanks, I made some edits.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Thanks, I thought every instance should have its field(s).

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks. Actually, I am not so clear about what is the (local) variables (though, I've read several times Chapter 5 "Variables" of the specification). I made some edits.

Comment: The first thing to be clear about is that `x` isn't an instance. It's a variable. It has a value, which is an integer. I'm afraid your question is still very unclear to me though.

Comment: @JonSkeet Hmmm. You could be right. I am thinking that I missed "s" in the sentence. It is a plural form not a single. "..We can perform functions such as arithmatic with instances of the int type as follows:". The instnaces should be "leterals" (12 and 30) not "x".

Comment: @JonSkeet Ok. But, questions still going on. Let me think about this line of code. int x = 1; Now, I put an "instance(1)" into a variable("x"). Is that right/possible ?

Comment: You've set the value of `x` to be 1, which is an `int` value, yes.

Comment: @JonSkeet Hmmm. I am still in ambiguity. Instance ("1") is not a value itself. If you want a value from it, you have to have(attach) a field. Something like this (it is just for the explanation) "int x = 1.foo ;". Am I wrong ?

Comment: Sorry, Stack Overflow isn't design for a conversational style like this. I suggest you edit your question to make it more directly answerable.  (But you *can* call methods etc directly on `int`, e.g. `string x = 1.ToString()`)

Comment: @Jason - I'm not sure where your confusion comes from, its either the assignment operator as my answer explains or the [difference between reference and value types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx)

Comment: and furthermore "x" is an instance. I saw some explanations (it should be CLR via C#). It goes like this; Full (just for explanations) style should be "int x = new int("1");" But, it is a primitive type, you can make it in a short style "int x = 1;". So I thought "x" is an instance for sure.

Comment: @JonSkeet OK. I am a very stranger here (joined YESTERDAY). The first thing to learn is the Q/A style of this community. I will try to learn it. THANKS. Regards..

Comment: @PaulF Thanks. I saw that sentence already. I guess I have to think it again and again (because, I do not understand it clearly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, `int` doesn't have a field to put the factors of the number that it is storing.

Ok, so first question: You can put stuff in the variable because it is an `int`. `int` variables are supposed to store numbers so you can use a number literal, such as `5` as a value for that variable. In your case, you don't put 12 * 30 into the variable, you put the *result* of 12 * 30 into the variable, which is 360. It's just like:

```
int x = 360;
```

They are *exactly* the same. There is no need to use fields of the `Int32` type.

Second question: You cannot. Just as I said before, you are putting 360 into the variable, not a multiplication expression. That means the variable doesn't know that when you assign 360 to the variable, you actually used 12 * 30. It just knows that you want to store 360. That's all. So if you want to store the expression in a variable, don't use int. Instead, use expression trees. [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)'s book, C# In Depth, introduces expression trees, you can have a look at that.

EDIT:

Now that you made it clearer, I can tell you that `int` do have a field, but it's private. You can go to referencesource.microsoft.com to look at the source code of int. But why cn you just assign a value to an int? Because that is the beauty of primitive types. They just let you do this. It's all about the CLR.

Comment: Thanks. At the first line, You catched the curiosity of mine exactly. Yes, if you do not have any field in your type (instance), you can not save/read the values. That is my only point here. (But, now I am the more confused with the very basic terms than earlier. What in the world is the variables ? What is the difference between variables and fields. Everybody says variables are not fields(or instances or objects). Is that right ? I do not know. I have to dig into some more books.) Thanks again.

Comment: ((Can you recommend me a good one ? I have Specifications 4th, NutShell 5.0, CLR via C# 4th and C# In Depth 3rd. I guess I need some more informations. I'm a beginner in C# and not a professional developer at all))  Regards

Comment: @Jason sorry I don't read books so I cannot recommend some more. But yes, (local) variables are not fields. Their difference is that variables are declared in methods while fields are declared in classes. You can access a field anywhere if it is public but you cannot access variables except in the method itself.

Comment: OK. Thanks. Have to think it over again.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're missing the point of what the [assignment operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691314%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) does.

> It assigns the value of the right operand to the variable, property, or indexer element given by the left operand.

In other words, `x` doesn't contain `12 * 30`, it contains the *result* of this.

So if you want your message box to show the exact string `"12 * 30"` then you need to set this value in a string as well, there are libraries around that can try to decipher this string into a mathematical formula to retrieve its result but since you have this already you can just create a string from this.

```
int x = 12;
int y = 30;
int z = x * y;
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} * {1} = {2}", x, y, z));
```

In answer to your second question, you can't. Your variable `x` (my `z`) has no knowledge of the operation that was performed in order to give it its value. The only "knowledge" it really has, is what its current value is.

Comment: Thanks for good and long explanation. Sorry, it's my fault. I made pointless questions. So, you made unrelated answer. My apologies again. Regards

Answer (score 1):

Change x to type string and initialise it with the value you want:

```
string x = (12 * 30).ToString();
MessageBox.Show(x);
```

...Or do you want

```
string x = "12 * 30";
```

Comment: Sorry, it is my fault. I made pointless questions. So, you made unrelated answer. My apologies again. Regards

Answer (score -1):

MessageBox.Show((12 * 30).ToString());

Comment: Thanks. But, I made some EDITs.